# Perl Hash Keys + Values to variable

Tags: perl, hash

So I have a hash table like this:

```
M => 1
S => 50
```

I want to do something like this:

```
$var = map { "$hash{$_}"."$_\n" } keys %hash;
print $var;
```

so that I end up with a variable to print that looks like:

```
1M50S
```

Unfortunately the map statement doesn't work :(
And yes it must be assigned to a variable because it is in an if statement and changes depending on conditions. Is there a nice clean way of doing this?

Comment: The `map` function works just fine, by the way.  :)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but I was referring to the map statement in my question.

Comment: He means that the map statement works fine; the assignment is what's not doing what you expect. Does it return 2?

Answer (score 4):

Just use reverse:

```
my %hash = (M => 1, S => 50);
my $var = reverse %hash;
## use the next line instead if you need sorting
#my $var = join '', map { $_ . $hash{ $_ } } reverse sort keys %hash;
## or this
#my $var = reverse map { $_ => $hash{ $_ } } reverse sort keys %hash;
print $var; ## outputs 1M50S
```

Answer (score 1):

You can, for example, concatenate first the value + key and then do a join:

```
%hash = (M => 1, S => 50);
$var = join("", map {$hash{$_} . $_}  keys %hash);
print $var . "\n" ;
```

Added: If you want to sort by values, asumming they are numeric:

```
%hash = (M => 1, S => 50, Z => 6);
$var = join("", map {$hash{$_} . $_}  sort { $hash{$a} <=> $hash{$b} } keys %hash);
print $var . "\n" ;

1M6Z50S
```

Comment: @Dan: `sort` the keys before mapping

Comment: @Dan: it depends on whether you want to sort by keys or values, and whether you want alfanumeric order or numeric. I added an example

Answer (score 1):

you have to know that `keys %hash` is unordered, which means its order may or may not be what you want.

I recommend using a ordered list here to specify keys.

and there is an unclean way

```
%time=(M=>1,S=>50);
$var=join"",map{"$time{$_}$_"}('M','S');
#=> $var='1M50S'
```

Comment: Is this a way to try and specify the order? By the way the M and S have no correlation to minutes and seconds. They are flags for another software, but it would be useful to be able to order the flags, since there are many more, all of these: `MIDNSHP=X`

Comment: Not sure what you meant by 'try', but yes you can specify the order like `map{block}(a_list_of_ordered keys)`

Answer (score 0):

If `MIDNSHP=X` is all of the keys in the order you want them, then write

```
my $var = join '', map "$hash{$_}$_", split //, 'MIDNSHP=X';
```

If the hash may contain less than a complete set of keys, then use this instead

```
my $var = join '', map "$hash{$_}$_", grep $hash{$_}, split //, 'MIDNSHP=X';
```

Comment: `grep $hash{$_}` will fail for empty string or zero values. You will need `grep defined $hash{$_}`